# Chrome header bar color isn't working

Tags: android, css, google-chrome

I've carried out the seemingly straightforward process of adding a "theme-color" so that the chrome address bar shows a color on android phones.

After checking it's implemented, the source for my website includes the following:

But, colours still don't show on my android phone. I've tried clearing the chrome cache, clearing cache on my backend, adding SSL certificates as one post suggested, but it still isn't working.

My website is [www.ananaclinic.co.uk](http://www.ananaclinic.co.uk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out -  hopefully this helps someone else later.

Basically, the colour I was trying to use as the theme-color wasn't saturated enough. When I tried other colors, or even more saturated versions of the same colour, it works.

It makes sense that Google doesn't want you to change the header color if it's a very slight difference from the normal grey. If it's too subtle it doesn't add anything to the website, and just makes it look like the grey is off colored.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the space between the theme and the author.
Also, your HTML isn't completely valid and PHP isn't running right.

Comment: What do you mean my html isn't valid? What exactly is the issue?

Comment: @MobyMotion at line 17 there's php code that isn't running